# How do I combine two lists to display the needed result?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two lists of same type. I uploaded the pic of what the list contains; third pic shows what data I need.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best approach but try using this:-

```
var stocksCount = items.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID)
                                 .Select(x => new { ItemID = x.Key, ItemCount = x.Count() }).ToList();

var result = from item in items
                             join stock in stocks
                             on item.ItemID equals stock.ItemID
                             select new
                             {
                                 item.ItemID,
                                 item.ItemName,
                                 item.ProcessId,
                                 item.ReqQTY,
                                 AllocatedStock = (stock.Stock / stocksCount.First(x => x.ItemID == item.ItemID).ItemCount)
                             };
```

Complete Fiddle [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O6HiQY).